# How to do RPA (Random Phase Approximation) in VASP?

Tags: density-functional-theory

I'm new to VASP and as such don't know much of its intricacies yet. I want to find out the interlayer binding energy of a given molecule and to do that I already opted for the use of different functionals (DFT-D3, SCAN, etc.) to find the total energy of my system in case of the bulk material and in case of the isolated layer. From these two I calculated the interlayer binding energy but am still about an order of magnitude of.

Now, I thought of using RPA in VASP to maybe get closer results. 
My question(s): How do I implement RPA into VASP? I've read the wiki entry on it but am still not sure how to modify the other INCAR tags. Do I add RPA while also utilizing some functional (i.e. one of those I already used) or is RPA sufficient on its own? 
And are there other methods with which I could get better values?